# How can I make texmaker open with multiple .tex files at once?

Tags: texmaker

I always open about 8 separate .tex files when I'm using texmaker, all from different directories. This is very inefficient so I was wondering is there some command I can use on the terminal to make texmaker automatically open all these files when it starts?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested answer for Ubuntu (or debian based) since I don't have TeXmaker installed.

In your

```
/usr/share/applications
```

folder, you possibly have a `texmaker.desktop` file.

If it is not there find it for your system (If you can already use texmaker with open with there is such a file. If not you can add it.)

If you open it with a texteditor like `nano`, you will find something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.9.4
Name=Texmaker
GenericName=LaTeX Editor
GenericName[fr]=Editeur LaTeX
Comment=LaTeX Editor
Comment[fr]=Editeur LaTeX
Exec=texmaker
Icon=texmaker
MimeType=text/x-tex;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Publishing;
```

Command for opening:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/texmaker.desktop
```

(Or nano instead of gedit... or whatever)

At the end of the line `Exec=texmaker` if you add `%U` you will get:

```
Exec=texmaker %U
```

This way texmaker can used with "open with"  to open files or folders.

If now you make the line like:

```
Exec=texmaker /home/Desktop/myFolderWith8Files/ %U
```

then, whenever you use "open with"... it will open the selected files or folder and the "default" `/home/Desktop/myFolderWith8Files/` folder

Comment: Thats seems like a good option my home laptop thanks! However, I really need to be able to do this from my work machine and unfortunately I've just check that texmaker.desktop file and it is read-only. Is the a workaround for this?

Comment: You can try in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: sudo vi texmaker.desktop