# Texmaker, how to open a directory?

Tags: texmaker

My tex project contains many `.tex` files, I must open every file in the project directory, apparently, it is very annoying.

[image]

In Texmaker, how can I open a text project instead of opening every file in the project directory?

Comment: [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397449/121799)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but with all the files open, you can save a session file with File -> Session -> Save session:

[image: Session menu in Texmaker]

Next time you start Texmaker, you can restart the previous session with the keyboard shortcut seen in the image (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>), or open a specific session file with File -> Session -> Load session.

Note also that when using the normal File -> Open, you can select multiple files to open.

Comment: Your answer has solved my question. Although texmaker couldn't open a containing folder, there is `Session` mechanism available to open previous projects. Thank you!